# Imacros how to enable an infinite loop?

Tags: loops, infinite, imacros

I just started imacro to use but i have no idea on how to set an infinite loop.

My code is this:

```
set !loop 3
VERSION BUILD=8530828 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
REFRESH
TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Like
TAB T=2
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL ATTR=ID:timelineHeadlineLikeButton
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
WAIT SECONDS=5

set !loop 3
VERSION BUILD=8530828 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
REFRESH
TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Like
TAB T=2
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL ATTR=ID:timelineHeadlineLikeButton
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET !VAR1 3
SET !VAR2 {{!LOOP}}
ADD !VAR1 -{{!VAR2}}
TAB T={{!VAR1}}
```

(3 means 2 because loop can not set 0)
or:

```
SET !VAR1 2
SET !VAR1 {{!LOOP}}
ADD !VAR1 {{!LOOP}}
ADD !VAR1 -1
TAB T={{!VAR1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop With Javascript:

```
var loop;
function play(loop) {
        for (i=0;i<loop,i++;) {
            iimPlay("macro.iim"); //Play Your Macro
}
}
play(999); //loops macro 999 times
```

You can loop through an array of data in a macro as well:

```
var loop;
var dataline;
function play(dataline,loop) {
        for (i=0;i<loop,i++;) {
            iimSet("dataline",dataline);  //set dataline (optional)
            iimPlay("macro.iim"); //Play Your Macro
}
}
play(3,999); //starts on datasource line 3 loops 999 times
```

Then in your .iim file

```
SET !DATASOURCE Address.csv //your csv datasource file
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{dataline}}  //start on that line
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT CONTENT={{!COL1}}  //1st line of your spreadsheet
```

Enjoy!

Comment: A bit of advice where to put the javascript? I have been using iMacros and I can only create .iim files. Not sure where I am supposed to add javascript code to do the loop

Answer (score -1):

Just run it with Play(Loop) button stating very big number in max box

```
TAB T=1
REFRESH
TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Like
TAB T=2
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL ATTR=ID:timelineHeadlineLikeButton
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

Comment: a big number is not infinite

Answer (score -1):

Here is an infinite loop that alerts and breaks on error and waits 10 seconds between each loop:

```
function play() {
    for (i=1;i>0,i++;) {
        iimPlay("macro.iim"); //Play Your Macro
        if (iimGetErrorText()!="OK") {  //if there is an error
            alert(iimGetErrorText()); //alert the error
            break;  //break loop on error
        }
        iimPlayCode("WAIT SECONDS=10"); //Wait 10 Seconds between each loop
    }
}
play();
```